# Scala: confusion with varargs

Tags: scala, android-studio, variadic-functions

I might have misunderstood something, but I thought the following would compile:

```
class Function(f:(Apfloat*) => Apfloat, args:Link*) extends Link {
  override def value:Apfloat = f((for (i <- args) yield i.value):_*)
}
```

but it instead, Android Studio gives me this error:

> Expansion for non-repeated parameter

I also tried without the :_* but then it gives me a type mismatch...

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1, scala plugin 1.5.4, android tools 1.3.1, android-scala-plugin 1.4, scala 2.11.7. Link is an abstract class (with just the abstract def value) and Apfloat is from the library with the same name, but I don't think that should matter. I'd be happy to provide any additional information.

Comment: This seems to work just fine. Can you paste the definition of Link and the complete error message?

Comment: `class Fun(f: (Int*) => Int, args: String*) { def value = f((for (i <- args) yield i.toInt): _*) }` this code compiles fine, similar to yours but we don't know your types. Btw you could use `args.map(_.value)` instead of `(for (i <- args) yield i.value)`

Comment: Seems Scala plugin can not infer correctly the type of vararg parameter in function literal. So it can be considered as a "IDE highlighting error". Reported to JetBrains. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-9857

Comment: @MarkusMarvell That's what I thought it was, thanks for reporting it, I wasn't sure how to do that.
@Łukasz Thank you for the `args.map` tip, I was wondering if there was something like that!